# Nginx Redirect one domain to sub folder inside another domain

Tags: dns, nginx

I have `product.com` and `company.com`

I would love to figure out how to tell both the DNS and Nginx to redirect `product.com` to a folder inside the `company.com` domain.

Ideally all these permutations

```
http://product.com
https://product.com
http://www.product.com
https://www.product.com
```

Redirect the user to a subfolder inside of `company.com` at

```
https://company.com/product
```

oh and

here is my current Nginx config for `company.com`

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name company.com www.company.com;

  if ($host = 'www.company.com') {
    return 301 https://company.com$request_uri;
  }

  root /var/www/company.com/html;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  include /etc/nginx/compression.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/php.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/assets.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/restrictions.conf;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/company.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/company.com/privkey.pem;
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name company.com www.company.com;
  return 301 https://company.com$request_uri;
}
```

Please let me know

1) What DNS records I would need for product.com, and compnay.com

2) What Nginx rule(s) I would need for product.com, and compnay.com

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have `https://company.com/product` working? Because that would be the first step.

Comment: *What DNS records I would need for product.com and company.com* - Just as a quick comment, this kind of redirection has nothing to do with DNS. So this would all be done with Nginx.

Comment: @RichardSmith yes and I just posted the current config, thanks for looking

Answer (score 0):

In nginx, I think a rewrite would do it. Something like:

```
rewrite ^/product(.*) https://$host/company.com/product$1 permanent;
```